# Use javascript to parse _ga cookie and return the client ID

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I'm looking to use javascript take the value of a _ga cookie:

GA1.1.233577256.1615161473

and return the last TWO number sections:

233577256.1615161473

(this is for cross-domain tracking and setting the clientId value of the iFrame GA tag, but that mostly irrelevant).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> you can use this snippet to get the id

```
    const pattern = "GA1.1.";
    const id = {{GA Cookie}}.substr(pattern.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. You have to replace `UA-XXXXXXXX-XX` with your Google Analytics Universal tracking code:

```
var trackers = ga.getAll();
var i, len;
for (i = 0, len = trackers.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  if (trackers[i].get('trackingId') === 'UA-XXXXXXXX-XX') {
    console.log(trackers[i].get('clientId'));
  }
}
```

And the result will be directly in the format like: *233577256.1615161473*

Comment: I had been trying to use this version (and other versions of the same), but for some reason this value isn't populating on clickfunnels pages in any sort of reliable manner. I might need a postback call url or something, but I'm not familiar with those.